# If Statements in Plain TeX

Tags: conditionals

In plain TeX, the following code:

```
\def\ver{a}

\if\ver{a}{yes}\else{no}\fi  

\ifx\ver{a}{yes}\else{no}\fi
```

returns

```
no

no
```

Is there some variant of "if" and "ifx" that will return "yes" ?   If not, is there some other way to do the equivalent logical test?  Using `\let` instead of `\def` doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*No primitive conditional in TeX interprets braced arguments.* Don't brace the true or false texts either.

In the case of `\if`, TeX performs complete macro expansion until finding two unexpandable tokens. In your situation, `\ver` is expanded to `a` and the following token is `{`, which is unexpandable.

Thus the comparison (of character codes) returns false and the text up to `\else` is skipped over and you remain with

```
\else{no}\fi
```

so at the end you get `{no}` that prints “no”.

To the contrary, `\ifx` does no expansion and comparest the two following tokens, in this case `\ver` and `{`.

The test

```
\if a\ver yes\else no\fi
```

will print “yes”.

Comment: Thank you!  .........

Answer (score 5):

In Plain TeX (`\def` is not expandable):

```
\def\tmp{a}
\ifx\tmp\ver Yes\else No\fi
```

In Optex (it is expandable):

```
\ismacro \ver{a}\iftrue Yes\else No\fi
```